# Woodmart theme Filter WooCommerce products by Color issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress website using Woodmart theme and WooCommerce plugin latest version, which has some products with different color variations.
Here is the [link to the shop page](https://syonafans.com/shop/) where we can see the FILTER BY COLOR option on the left side panel. The default color of the product is set to brown, and we filter the product by color (choosing white or ivory…). It still shows the brown color product. We have added all the variations, attributes properly and uploaded the images as per the color attribute. We are not using any third party plugin for filter, as this functionality is included in the Woodmart theme.

Here are some screenshots:

**Product Variations**

[image]

**Color Attributes**

[image]

**Default product image and default product gallery**

[image]

I have tried to show the single product variation that is show all the products without grouping them with color attributes, like product 1 has 3 colors (brown, ivory and white) and product 2 has 3 colors (brown, ivory and white).

So totally 6 products will be shown as single products, now that I don't want that option I reverted it back with the 2 products with 3 color attributes.

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

After enabling and disabling, it caused the issue.

Comment: Did you resaved each variable product after disabling the option (on your last screenshot, it's recommended to resave each product)? As this seems to be related to Woodmart theme, you should search and ask in the theme author's support pages.

Comment: I did resaved all the variables for all the products after disabling it. Still its not working. Not sure what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to WooCommerce > Status > Tools and click on Regenerate the product attributes lookup table:

Screenshot: https://take.ms/LGpvf